# Evaluate the limit when $x$ approaches $0$

Tags: calculus

I do not understand how he did this. Isn't $\tan (3x)$ just $\sin (3x) / \cos (3x)$, and not the other way around?
$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-1}{\tan(3x)}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\underset{\large\to1}{\enclose{circle}{\bbox[2pt]{\frac{e^{2x}-1}{2x}}}}\frac{\overset{\large\to1}{\enclose{circle}{\bbox[2pt]{\cos(3x)}}}}{\underset{\large\to1}{\enclose{circle}{\bbox[1pt]{\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x}}}}}\cdot\frac1{\frac32}\\
&=1\cdot\frac11\cdot\frac1{\frac32}=\frac23
\end{align}
$$

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtO5y.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: But you have $\frac1{\tan x} $ not $\tan x$.

Comment: That crappy sheet is right.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps for solving this

You need to apply L'Hospital rule once after rewriting.

[image]

Comment: Use MathJax to write equations, *do not* post images.